# How to implement email sending on behalf of a user in Microsoft Azure AD

Tags: reactjs, azure, email, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

What is the recommended architecture using Microsoft Azure AD to implement delayed mail sending on behalf of a user in a React frontend and Python backend?

I want the user to connect to their Microsoft account in the frontend and obtain the necessary tokens in my backend for subsequent use in sending emails on behalf of the user.

Should I use OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect for the user authentication in my frontend?

I am currently using MSAL in my frontend to allow the user to connect to their Microsoft account, but I am unable to obtain a refresh token in my backend. I have set my frontend as an SPA and my backend as a web application in Azure AD, but I am not sure if this is the correct configuration. Are there any best practices or recommended approaches to achieve this?

Progress shareing:

prog 1:

I obtained an authorization code in my frontend by following the instructions on this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/energy-data-services/how-to-generate-refresh-token#get-authorization.

I then sent this authorization code to my backend to obtain a refresh token, but I am encountering an error that says 'AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.'

I suspect that the error is caused by the fact that I'm using different uri's in my frontend and backend. If this is the case, how can I pass the information needed to get the refresh token to my backend?

[Both endpoints included in web urls in Azure AD]

prog 2:

I have obtained an access_token using this method, but I am unable to obtain a refresh token. While the "client_credentials" grant_type works, the "authorization_code" grant_type is not working for me. I am unsure whether the issue lies with Azure AD or if I am not sending the correct body parameters.

prog 3:
Successfully obtain both an access token and a refresh token.

prog 4:
failed to send mail:

"{'error': {'code': 'ErrorAccessDenied', 'message': 'Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.'}}"

prog 5:
Email sent but the sender is user-id@outlook.com instead of user-email@domain.xx

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: If you want send mail on behalf of a user **`client_credentials`**  flow. Use **`Authorization code`** flow for user interaction.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application** and added Application permission:

[image]

I generated **access token using Client Credentials** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

To send mail, I used below query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/FromAddress/sendMail

{
"message": {
"subject": "hi",
"body": {
"contentType": "Text",
"content": "how are you"
},
"toRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"address": "****"
}
}
],
"ccRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"address": "****"
}
]
},
"saveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

[image]

As mentioned by you, using  **Authorization code** is not working.

I created an **Azure AD Application** and added Delegated permissions:

[image]

I generated **auth-code** using below endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=mail.send offline_access
&state=12345
```

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:ClientID
scope:mail.send offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

To send mail, I used below query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail

{
"message": {
"subject": "hi",
"body": {
"contentType": "Text",
"content": "how are you"
},
"toRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"address": "****"
}
}
],
"ccRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"address": "****"
}
]
},
"saveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[user: sendMail - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive response. Can you provide information on how to modify the "from" field? in the current code I set the "from" field as follows:

"from": {
"emailAddress": {
"name": "Test",
"address": f"{user['userPrincipalName']}"
}
}

However, the email I receive is from "outlook_Euid@outlook.com" instead of "mail@outlook.com".